# Is there a way to get back tokens from lexical analysis in Azure Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-analysis-services

Is it possible to get back tokens that Azure Search creates during its lexical analysis (as described in Microsoft’s [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture))?

I saw that you can call Analyze API to generate tokens for a given text input, but since that approach would still require me to build a query parser to separate term and phrase queries, I was wondering if I might be missing some Azure Search’s built-in capability?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on "Azure Search’s built-in highlighting option is not flexible enough for my scenario"? What is your scenario?

Comment: @JacobJedryszek I've edited that part out as it wasn't a fair statement since it was more a matter of our architecture that involves multiple data sources than an Azure highlighting capability. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the Analyze API? it shows how an analyzer breaks text into tokens. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer#analyze-api-example

Comment: I saw that option, but I was just wondering if it's possible to get a response similar to that one inside the Azure search response. Looks like I might be looking at the two API requests after all :) Thank you!